# ASP.NET to Webmethod via AJAX - Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type \u0027System.String\u0026\u0027

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, vb.net, webmethod

I've done a search on this and tried loads of different answers and just can't get my code working from the examples.

I'm trying to send username and password to a webservice through ajax.

my .js is:

```
    $("#btnLogin").click(function () {

        var user = $('#username').val();
        var pass = $('#password').val();

        var myData = {
            Username: user,
            Password: pass
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "plinth/verification/LogMeIn.aspx/VerifyLogIn",
            data: JSON.stringify(myData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processdata: true,  
            traditional: true,
            success: callBackFunction,
            error: function (msg) { alert(msg); }
        });



    });
```

And my LogMeIn.aspx is:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="LogMeIn.aspx.vb" Inherits="AspenBridging.LogMeIn2" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Services" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function VerifyLogIn(ByRef Username As String, ByRef Password As String) As String

        Return "Hello!"

    End Function

</script>
```

The error I'm currently getting is:

> {"Message":"Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to
>   type \u0027System.String\u0026\u0027","StackTrace":"   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object
>   o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object
>   o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2
>   rawParams)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object
>   target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

I've tried loads of things and I'm hoping it's something really simple I've overlooked but just cant figure it out.

Any help is super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.  Changed my LogMeIn.aspx to a .asmx (WebService) and seemed to have worked fine.